# Почему цыплята - табака?

Tags: этимология

Есть такое всем известное блюдо - цыпленок табака. Интересно, а при чем тут, собственно, табак? Почему оно так называется?
Спасибо

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Табак тут ни при чём. Точнее, слово "табак" похоже на слово "тапак" (название сковородки, в которой традиционно готовится это блюдо), и народная этимология решила заменить грузинское слово на русское, так и прижилось.

Answer (score 1):

слово "таба", "табак" есть во всех тюркских языках, в грузинском является заимствованным и означает не сковорода, а плоская тарелка. Поскольку цыпленка в процессе приготовления блюда "плющили" как тарелку, а затем  обжаривали и весь гарнир- помидорный соус, лук, хлеб клали на цыпленка, поэтому блюдо и назвали "цыпленок- табак". Кстати, в грузинской кухне есть посуда "кеци"- каменная сковорода, от тюркского "кесе"- пиала.Этимология

груз. ტაფა tapha — «сковорода», возможно происходит от арабского слова طبق tabbaq — «блюдо», «поднос», «тарелка».
Распространенное название блюда в Армении тапакац хав — дословно «жареная курица» или «сплющенная курица».
Вероятно, все названия восходят к арабскому «tabbaq» и его первоначальному значению «плоский», «плоскость», «раздавленный», (отсюда «лист» [в смысле «расплющенный, плоский»] как название табачного листа — листа растения, которое называлось «тутун» (ср. укр. «тютюн»).

Comment: >в грузинском является заимствованным  
  
??????

А все переводчику врут?

Comment: >в грузинском является заимствованным и означает не сковорода, а плоская тарелка.  
>груз. ტაფა tapha — «сковорода»,  
  
Ну так либо - либо.    

Про заимствование как таковое - ну это может быть, не буду спорить, не знаток.

Answer (score 0):

По фени *табак* – это *хана*, т. е. цыплёнок, это жертва, жертвенный цыплёнок.